Best way to display and manipulate a "pyramid" of numbers
One can create a triangle of numbers from a list of lists, where the first sublist is of length 1 and the next sublists are one element longer than the previous, for example: TableForm[Table[Binomial[n, k], {n, 0, 4}, {k, 0, n}]]. Here we are explicitly displaying this triangle using TableForm.
One can go further and create a "pyramid" of numbers from a list of lists-of-lists, where the lists-of-lists are of the form above, i.e. a pyramid is a list of triangles. For example: TableForm[Table[Multinomial[n1,n2,l-n1-n2],{l,0,4},{n1,0,l},{n2,0,l-n1}]]. Here, again, we are explicitly displaying this triangle using `TableForm'.
Is there a better way to display this information, specifically the pyramids? Perhaps something like a Graphics3D to be able to manipulate and move around the pyramid to be able to see how the layers stack on top of each other better?

Here's a start: Graphics3D[{   MapIndexed[    Text,    Table[     Multinomial[n1, n2, l - n1 - n2], {l, 0, 4}, {n1, 0, l}, {n2, 0,       l - n1}],    {3}]   }]. There may be a best way, but right now, I'm not sure what a good way is. Maybe something will occur to me.

It shows the layers:
pyr = Graphics3D[{
   MapIndexed[
    Text[Style[#, Bold, Darker@Blue, 12], #2 - 1] &,
    Table[
     Multinomial[n1, n2, l - n1 - n2], {l, 0, 4}, {n1, 0, l}, {n2, 0, 
      l - n1}],
    {3}]
   }, Axes -> True, AxesEdge -> {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, Black, Bold] & /@ {l, Subscript[n, 1], 
      Subscript[n, 2]}), BaseStyle -> GrayLevel[0.6]]

GraphicsRow[
 Show[pyr, ViewPoint -> #, 
    ViewVertical -> #2] & @@@ {{{3.5, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 
     1}}, {{-1, -3.5, -1}, {-1, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, -3.5}, {0, 1, 0}}}]


